# Ruby 2.0 is not a valid platform

Tags: ruby, phusion, openproject

Hi all I am working with Phusion Passenger and I go to run my web app and it gives me Ruby 2.0 is not a valid platform. Here is my output below, any ideas?

Thanks!

```
ruby_20` is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19] (Bundler::DslError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:209:in `block in _normalize_options'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:207:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:207:in `_normalize_options'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:56:in `gem'
  /home/bistro/openproject/Gemfile:82:in `evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `instance_eval'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:124:in `load'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in `running_bundler'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

I have tried updating Ruby Gems, Updating Bundler, reinstalling Phusion - and I am not sure what else to do.  Any thoughts?

Update 2:

I updated the Gem files in the Open project directory and still nothing.

It looks like Bundle updated now I am getting a different error:

```
Cannot execute "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/buildout/agents/SpawnPreparer": No such file or directory (errno=2) Application root /home/bistro/openproject Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV) production Ruby interpreter command /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 User and groups Unknown Environment variables Unknown Ulimits Unknown
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This message by itself might not be helpful enough for us to give you a good answer.  What have you tried?

Comment: Hi Rob, thank you. I have tried updating Ruby Gems, Updating Bundler, reinstalling Phusion - and I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: That's a good start :-) I added it to your question for you; edits and updates increase the visibility of your question a little bit.

Comment: I updated the Gem files in the Open project directory and still nothing.

Comment: Sorry  for the spam. It looks like Bundle updated now I am getting a different error

Cannot execute "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.29/buildout/agents/SpawnPreparer": No such file or directory (errno=2)
Application root
/home/bistro/openproject
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV and PASSENGER_ENV)
production
Ruby interpreter command
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
User and groups
Unknown
Environment variables
Unknown
Ulimits
Unknown

Comment: Don't kill me --- now it is back. Still the same error Ruby 20 is not a valid platform.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the error itself?

`ruby_20 is not a valid platform. The available options are: [:ruby, :ruby_18, :ruby_19, :mri, :mri_18, :mri_19, :rbx, :jruby, :mswin, :mingw, :mingw_18, :mingw_19] (Bundler::DslError`

there's probably a config file somewhere that has "ruby_20" in it, but according to the error, the values allowed don't include that.

Comment: Search for `ruby_20` in your source and replace it with `ruby`

Comment: please post your `Gemfile`

Comment: @user3120330 do you still have this error with the recent sources from the OpenProject github `dev` branch?

Comment: `ruby_20 is not a valid platform.` - That error is displayed by bundler. Bundler itself is outdated in that it does not support ruby 2.0 as a platform. You simply need to update the bundler gem itself. `gem update bundler` should do the trick, afterwards a `bundle install` should work just fine.